# is json package included in Python for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, json

is json package included in Python for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module is part of the Python standard library since version 2.6. All standard Python library modules are available on all platforms unless specifically indicated otherwise.

Comment: json used not to be included when it was on Linux. And also there was a naming problem with simplejson I think... Anyway, thanks for the quick answer.